# SQL query to list Unique user visits by Month

Tags: sql, powershell

I have a simple table with two columns I'm interested in:

`User`, `RequestTime`  (RequestTime is standard date and time)

What I want to do is output how many unique users there are per month.
**A simple output list like the following:**

```
Nov-2012,302  
Dec-2012,260  
Jan-2013,440  
Feb-2013,370
```

Ultimately this is going to be done via SQL query in PowerShell (if that matters)
I could easily figure out how to list each unique user and how many "visits" each had by doing:

```
    SELECT username, 
       Count(username)  AS 'RequestsPerUser', 
       Max(requesttime) AS 'MostRecentLicense' 
FROM   dbo.servicerequestview 
WHERE  requesttype = 'GetClientLicensorCert' 
       AND success = 1 
GROUP  BY username
```

but trying to get the an output like the example above with unique users per month has me stumped.

This code doesn't work but it was my latest attempt to get the output I want:

```
SELECT Count(DISTINCT username) AS 'UniqueUser', 
       Month(requesttime)       AS 'Month', 
       Year(requesttime)        AS 'Year' 
FROM   dbo.servicerequestview 
WHERE  requesttype = 'GetClientLicensorCert' 
       AND success = 1 
GROUP  BY year, 
          month 
ORDER  BY year, 
          month
```

I'm a little new at this so I'm probably way off.

Any pointing me in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: What exactly are you asking for here? A query? A PowerShell script to run the query? What have you done so far (show your code) and where have you gotten stuck?

Comment: Hopefully I won't confuse things, but the specific scenario is querying a Rights Management Server database.
This is what I'm doing to get a list of each unique user and how many licenses they got total:
"SELECT UserName,COUNT(UserName) AS 'RequestsPerUser',MAX(RequestTime) AS 'MostRecentLicense' FROM dbo.ServiceRequestView WHERE RequestType='GetClientLicensorCert' AND Success=1 GROUP BY UserName"

This works great. Now they want to know how many unique users there are per month acquiring a license. That has me stumped.

Comment: But you still haven't answered the questions.

Comment: Ran out of space in the comments :(
This code doesn't work but it was my latest attempt to get the output I want:
"SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT UserName) AS 'UniqueUser', MONTH(RequestTime) AS 'Month', YEAR(RequestTime) AS 'Year' FROM dbo.ServiceRequestView WHERE RequestType='GetClientLicensorCert' AND Success=1 GROUP BY year,Month ORDER BY Year,Month"

I'm a little new at this so I'm probably way off.

Comment: Don't put code & explanations in comments. Edit them into the original post.

Comment: Thanks. I'm new to using this forum too :)
Done.

Answer (score 0):

`Get-Unique` will work on a sorted list, run with `Get-Help` to find out more:

`Get-Help Get-Unique`

Comment: Thanks.  That's actually the part I can do (I'm doing it via a SQL query in PowerShell).  The part I can't figure out is how to count how many unique users have entries per month.
So if there are users Bob Dave and Joe. If Bob has multiple entries for January, it still should be counted as 1.